# How to Bind on_press to GridLayout in kivy python

Tags: python, kivy

i was trying to bind on_press method to gridLayout in kv language but i got this error  **AttributeError: pressed**. I did some research even in the kivy doc but no help .So if any one has a solution to this problem please you may be a good resource

here is my testApp.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

class screendb(BoxLayout):
      def mycall_back(self):
          print('hello')

class testApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return screendb()

if __name__=='__main__':
     testApp().run()
```

here is my testApp.kv

```
<Screendb@BoxLayout>:
        GridLayout:
             on_pressed:root.Mycall_back()
```

Comment: Welcome to [es.so] Ronald. You shoudn't post images of code or error messages, copy and paste or type the actual code or message into the post directly instead. See [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186/344172). On the other hand, `GridLayout` does not have the `on_release` event defined, as Button has for example.

Comment: Thanks for the reply FJSevilla

Comment: i have edited my question

Comment: AND is there anyway i can add the on_release to the GridLayout or any layout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your py file:

```
# Behaviors let you add behavior from one widget to another widget
from kivy.uix.behaviors import ButtonBehavior
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout

# We create a new widget that is a GridLayout with access to Button Behaviors
# Like Button's 'on_press' method
class ButtonGrid(ButtonBehavior, GridLayout):
    pass

class screendb(BoxLayout):
      def mycall_back(self):
          print('hello')

class testApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return screendb()
```

In your kv file:

```
# We create a Root Widget for the ButtonGrid
<ButtonGrid>:

<Screendb@BoxLayout>:
    # We add an instance of the ButtonGrid class to our main layout
    ButtonGrid:
        # We can now use on_press because it is a part of the ButtonBehavior class, that makes up your ButtonGrid class.
        on_press:root.mycall_back()
```

Note: There were a few minor mistakes in your post as well. For example, there is no method 'on_pressed', only 'on_press', you also wrote your callback as 'mycall_back' in your py file while writing it as 'Mycall_back' in your kv file, which refers to a different method that exists. Make sure your letter cases match.

[video example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UROD1cmP8Z8&feature=youtu.be)